# mdadm build legacy array on boot

Tags: raid, fstab, mdadm

I have RAID0 that was built using windows dynamic disk. I've read that this is a legacy array and can be assembled using build in mdadm. I've gotten the array to build and mount using the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/md0 /media/raid
```

This works great!

Now I'm working on getting this array to mount on boot. I've added the following entry to fstab:

```
 /dev/md0 /media/raid ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

This is where my problem arises. Before md0 can be mounted though, it needs to be assembled. Everything I've read says to run the following:

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan
```

And to put the output into mdadm.conf. However the output is:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=
```

Since the array is legacy, it does not have a uuid or any meta-data, and mdadm can't build it solely off `ARRAY /dev/md0` in the conf file.

What should I put into mdadm.conf in order for the raid to be assembled in legacy mode on boot?